# How to use count and where function in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Need some help here..have been stuck for awhile.

List all Name, Company Name of clients who have applied more than 2 loans which has a yearly repayment plan.

I should get 3 outputs:

```
John Tan, Happy Food Industry Pte Ltd
Mary Lee, Nice Man Advertising Pte Ltd
Yuyu Lee, NAGM Tuition Centre
```

My dataset:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John Tan",
    "contact_number": [
      "81726351",
      "92019283",
      "90192837"
    ],
    "company_name": "Happy Food Industry Pte Ltd",
    "company_registration_number": 950001819,
    "type_of_ownership": "owner",
    "last_roll_call": "16-06-21",
    "follow_up_notes": "Do not require any loan at this moment",
    "need_to_follow_up": "Yes",
    "plan_next_call": "01-12-21",
    "financial_year_ended": "30-06-21",
    "profit_and_lost_as_on_last_closing": 8000,
    "cumulative_profit_and_lost_as_on_last_closing": 50000,
    "loan_applied": [
      "Purchase of delivery lorry",
      "Renovation of tuition centre"
    ],
    "commission_date": "01-12-19",
    "loan_duration_in_mths": 24,
    "interest_rate": 3,
    "repayment_plan": "yearly",
    "loan_amount": 138058298,
    "status": "Requesting for delay payments",
    "other_notes": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Mary Lee",
    "contact_number": [
      "95213355"
    ],
    "company_name": "Nice Man Advertising Pte Ltd",
    "company_registration_number": 960087657,
    "type_of_ownership": "Partner with 50% holding",
    "last_roll_call": "15-06-21",
    "follow_up_notes": "Do not require any loan at this moment",
    "need_to_follow_up": "Yes",
    "plan_next_call": "Dec 21",
    "financial_year_ended": "30-01-21",
    "profit_and_lost_as_on_last_closing": 9000,
    "cumulative_profit_and_lost_as_on_last_closing": 40000,
    "loan_applied": [
      "Purchase of crane",
      "Purchase of machinery from USA"
    ],
    "commission_date": "01-11-19",
    "loan_duration_in_mths": 23,
    "interest_rate": 4,
    "repayment_plan": "yearly",
    "loan_amount": 1237162,
    "status": "Healthy",
    "other_notes": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Yuyu Lee",
    "contact_number": [
      "928371623"
    ],
    "company_name": "NAGM Tuition Centre",
    "type_of_ownership": "Partner with 20% holding",
    "follow_up_notes": "Do not require any loan at this moment",
    "need_to_follow_up": "Yes",
    "plan_next_call": "12-12-21",
    "financial_year_ended": "30-01-21",
    "profit_and_lost_as_on_last_closing": 1000000,
    "cumulative_profit_and_lost_as_on_last_closing": 3002000,
    "loan_applied": [
      "Purchase of raw material from China",
      "Renovation of shopping mall"
    ],
    "commission_date": "01-11-19",
    "loan_duration_in_mths": 11,
    "interest_rate": 4,
    "repayment_plan": "yearly",
    "loan_amount": 918272,
    "status": "Completed",
    "other_notes": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Joseph Lee",
    "contact_number": [
      "918273615",
      "0192837176",
      "1827361923"
    ],
    "company_name": "Akaka Tuition Centre",
    "company_registration_number": 929381782,
    "type_of_ownership": "Director",
    "last_roll_call": "15-11-21",
    "follow_up_notes": "Do not require any loan at this moment",
    "need_to_follow_up": "No",
    "plan_next_call": null,
    "financial_year_ended": "30-01-21",
    "profit_and_lost_as_on_last_closing": 999999,
    "cumulative_profit_and_lost_as_on_last_closing": 9000,
    "loan_applied": "Purchase of delivery lorry",
    "commission_date": "01-11-19",
    "loan_duration_in_mths": 11,
    "interest_rate": 4,
    "repayment_plan": "monthly",
    "loan_amount": 918272,
    "status": "Completed",
    "other_notes": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Tan Meh Meh",
    "contact_number": [
      "92837162",
      "9189278371"
    ],
    "company_name": "Target Pte Ltd",
    "company_registration_number": 293891823,
    "type_of_ownership": "Director",
    "last_roll_call": "15-12-21",
    "follow_up_notes": "Do not require any loan at this moment",
    "need_to_follow_up": "Yes",
    "plan_next_call": "09-12-21",
    "financial_year_ended": "30-01-21",
    "profit_and_lost_as_on_last_closing": 12500000,
    "cumulative_profit_and_lost_as_on_last_closing": 1500000,
    "loan_applied": "Purchase of delivery lorry",
    "commission_date": "01-11-19",
    "loan_duration_in_mths": 55,
    "interest_rate": 4,
    "repayment_plan": "monthly",
    "loan_amount": 918272,
    "status": "Completed",
    "other_notes": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Teo Bee Bee",
    "contact_number": [
      "92039189278",
      "192838182",
      "192837172"
    ],
    "company_name": "Hello Kitty Pte Ltd",
    "company_registration_number": 102039192,
    "type_of_ownership": "Owner",
    "last_roll_call": "13-11-21",
    "follow_up_notes": "Do not require any loan at this moment",
    "need_to_follow_up": "Yes",
    "plan_next_call": "09-01-21",
    "financial_year_ended": "30-01-21",
    "profit_and_lost_as_on_last_closing": 6000,
    "cumulative_profit_and_lost_as_on_last_closing": 24000000,
    "loan_applied": "Purchase of delivery lorry",
    "commission_date": "01-11-19",
    "loan_duration_in_mths": 33,
    "interest_rate": 4,
    "repayment_plan": "monthly",
    "loan_amount": 2312333,
    "status": "Requesting for delay payments",
    "other_notes": null
  }
]
```

Comment: show the query you have attempted

Answer (score 0):

The following query will get you what is needed.

```
db.collection.find( { "loan_applied.1": {  "$exists": true }, "repayment_plan": "yearly" } , {"name":1, "company_name": 1} );
```

Explanation:

Since `loan_applied` is an array field, we can use the dot notation to see if any element exist after the index `1`, which means more than 1 element. We add one more filter for `repayment_plan`.

In the second part of the query, we use projection to return back only `name` and `company_name`.

Comment: hi thanks very much for your reply. however can I ask how come I got an error: $size needs a number in my output?

Comment: You can check now

Comment: sorry I need at least 15 reputation to upvote.. I will upvote once I gotten it